# how to perform merge into/upsert from azure databricks on Azure SQL tables

Tags: pyspark, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, upsert

This is an ETL job. The transformations of data are written in Pyspark in Databricks, and the final data is loaded to Azure SQL tables. Say I have 100 records from yesterday in final table, and I get 50 records for today. If the 50 records are duplicates of yesterday's records, I am going to have a primary key violation issue and the write operation will fail in Databricks.

So if the record already exists, I have to update with latest values, otherwise insert the new records.

All the resources I checked mentioned to perform Merge into operation but what happens is I have to overwrite the entire table and cannot just update/replace one record directly in Azure SQL table.

Is there any way to update just one record at a time without overwriting the entire table? Because the final table will keep growing and it is risky and time consuming to overwrite every day.

Can we use stored procedures and call it from Databricks?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it simply by specifying your requirement to the update statement inside a proc and run that from databricks using pyodbc. But you have to know which ID you are going to update, or somehow be able to parameterize it based on some condition.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Name = 'Leet'
WHERE ID = 1337;
```

Lets say this is your update.

and in databricks:

```
import pyodbc

server = 'server.database.windows.net'
database = 'database'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
conn_str = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str) 
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Give your params here
id = 1337
new_name = 'Leet'

update_query = f"UPDATE Table1 SET Name = '{new_name}' WHERE ID = {id}"
cursor.execute(update_query, new_name, id)
conn.commit()
```

or you can do the last part like this:

```
update_query = "UPDATE YourTable SET Name = ? WHERE ID = ?"
cursor.execute(update_query, new_name, id)
```

then close the connection, this should work but I havent tested now. This in general is how you call a proc from databricks.

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood your question, regarding updating one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Following the above mentioned answer by @Ziya, below is how I achieved using pyodbc.

Install pyodbc:

Refer https://pub.towardsai.net/databricks-upsert-to-azure-sql-using-pyspark-5937e8303fbf

```
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc
```

Write Merge into Query:

```
upsert_query = f"""MERGE INTO APD_TEMP.TARGET_TBL AS Target USING APD_TEMP.SRC_TBL AS Source
ON Target.SrcCode = Source.SrcCode
   AND Target.Date = Source.Date
   AND Target.CC = Source.CC
   AND Target.ON = Source.ON
   AND Target.Country = Source.Country
   AND Target.CatCode = Source.CatCode
   AND Target.IDNo = Source.IDNo
   AND Target.InfoCode = Source.InfoCode
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
   SET Target.Time = Source.Time,
       Target.Qty = Source.Qty,
       Target.ValueTxt = Source.ValueTxt,
       Target.UpdateTimestamp = Source.UpdateTimestamp
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (SrcCode, Date, CC, ON, Country, CatCode, IDNo, Time, Qty, ValueTxt, CreationTimestamp, UpdateTimestamp, InfoCode)
      VALUES (Source.SrcCode, Source.Date, Source.CC,
    Source.ON, Source.Country, Source.CatCode,
    Source.IDNo,
    Source.Time, Source.Qty,
    Source.ValueTxt, Source.CreationTimestamp, Source.UpdateTimestamp, Source.InfoCode);"""
```

Execute the above:

```
cursor.execute(upsert_query)
conn.commit()
```